# LibSVM using Weka command line

Tags: weka, libsvm

I am trying to use LibSVM from weka command line but it gives me error:
**Error: Could not find or load main class weka.classifiers.functions.LibSVM**
I tried `java -cp weka.jar:LibSVM.jar:"C:\wekafiles\packages\LibSVM\LibSVM.jar":"\wekafiles\packages\LibSVM\lib\libsvm.jar" weka.classifiers.functions.LibSVM -S 0 -K 1 -D 3 -G 0.0 -R 0.0 -N 0.5 -M 40.0 -C 1.0 -E 0.001 -P 0.1 -model D:\Weka-3-8-5 -seed 1` Other ML algorithms works but the one I installed using weka are not working from command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you installed LibSVM as a Weka package, you should run it using the [weka.Run](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/Run.html) class instead of assembling the classpath manually:

```
java -cp weka.jar weka.Run .LibSVM -S 0 -K 1 -D 3 -G 0.0 -R 0.0 -N 0.5 -M 40.0 -C 1.0 -E 0.001 -P 0.1 -model D:\Weka-3-8-5 -seed 1
```

Of course, you still need to supply other parameters to this command-line, like training and/or test data.

The added benefit of using `weka.Run`, you don't need to supply the full classname of the classifier either (as long as there is no other class with that name).